# How do you group items that have dependencies to other items in a collection?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, dictionary, enumeration

I need to find a nice, clean way of getting a `IDictionary<string, ICollection<string>>` of fields and their related dependencies. The way that is determined is by going through a bunch of collections, looking for that field to be in that collection, and then finding all of its distinct dependencies. Example code:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    ICollection<string> Dependencies { get; }
}

public abstract class Foo<T> : IFoo
{
    protected Foo(ICollection<string> dependencies)
    {
        Dependencies = dependencies;
    }

    public ICollection<string> Dependencies { get; private set; }
}

public class FooA1 : Foo<A>
{
    public FooA1()
        :base(new Collection<string>() { "Amount", "CustomerDate", "AppointmentDate" }) { }
 }

public class FooA2 : Foo<A>
{
    public FooA2()
        :base(new Collection<string>() { "Amount", "AppointmentDate", "SomethingElse" }) { }
 }

public class FooA3 : Foo<A>
{
    public FooA3()
        :base(new Collection<string>() { "SomethingElse", "Something" }) { }
}
```

---

Essentially, what I'm trying to achieve would look like:

> Amount => CustomerDate, AppointmentDate, SomethingElse
>   CustomerDate => Amount, AppointmentDate
>   AppointmentDate => Amount, CustomerDate, SomethingElse
>   SomethingElse => Amount, AppointmentDate, Something
>   Something => SomethingElse

Now, I know how to get the list of all of the fields (assume I have a list of all the instances already): `instances.SelectMany(i => i.Dependencies).Distinct();`

The problem is, how do you get the list of all of the dependencies on that field in a nice clean fashion (preferably using LINQ).

Comment: You cannot override a property and change the access modifier. Furthermore, why do you need to override the property at all?

Comment: Why do you create separates classes for each set of these string values?

Comment: @rae1: Fixed that, that was just bad copy/paste when refactoring.

Comment: @bejger: The classes need to be able to state what codes they use (which other classes will utilize). But, what I need is a way for me to get the dependencies of a code on all of the types of Foos. For example, "Amount" relies on CustomerDate and AppointmentDate in `FooA1` and SomethingElse in `FooA2`.

Comment: Based on the code example, how are you arriving to the `Amount => CustomerDate, AppointmentDate, SomethingElse` relationship. How can `Amount` be th independent object when it is listed as part a dependency?

Comment: @rae1: I want to find all dependencies, or relationships. Basically, if "Amount" is in any `Dependencies` collection, then it has a relationship to every other string in that collection. Same with all other strings across all of the collections.

Answer (score 2):

This outputs what you're asking for.  It was the first thing I came up with and there may be an optimization that can be made in it somewhere.

```
var nice = instances.SelectMany(instance => instance.Dependencies)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(dependency => new { d = dependency, o = instances.Where(instance => instance.Dependencies.Contains(dependency)).SelectMany(instance => instance.Dependencies).Except(new string[] { dependency }).Distinct() })
    .Select(a => a.d + " => " + string.Join(", ", a.o));

// If you're in LINQPad
nice.Dump();
```

Outputs:

> Amount => CustomerDate, AppointmentDate, SomethingElse
>   CustomerDate => Amount, AppointmentDate
>   AppointmentDate => Amount, CustomerDate, SomethingElse
>   SomethingElse => Amount, AppointmentDate, Something
>   Something => SomethingElse